# при сохранении файла Prettier переносит теги на новую строку разрывая скобы и элементы, что можно сделать?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier

к примеру я создаю новый проект React и удаляю все лишнее с index.js
чистый документ

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

далее сохраняю документ и все форматируется автоматом и выводит предупреждения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в настройках:

html whitespace sensitivity - ignore,
jsx bracket same line - true

Comment: добавил в настройках выше перечисленное. не помогло.